# How to Zip two numbers using c#

Tags: c#

string A = "1234"
string B = "567890"

I want to zip the numbers. Out put should display as "1526374890"

what is the best way to achieve this using C# code.

Comment: You should include your attempted code in your question (edit it). If you haven't tried anything yet then go and do so, and come back when you have something to show

Comment: Something to go on: Loop the longest length, pop a letter off each string (if available), add it to an overall 'result' string.

Comment: Just pointing out, this is a custom interleaved concatenation, not a zip. Zip is a compression algorithm.

Comment: use the word concatenate rather than zip. Strings can be concatenated using the + operator. Therefore A+B

Comment: @joe The question is not about concatenation.  Look closely at the desired result.

Comment: @Kevin Zip is also used to describe an algorithm that matches up items at the same index like the [`Enumberable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: @juharr Maybe it's just my old-school showing. We sometimes called that kind of interleaving a zipper, never just a zip. Zip has been around since the late 70s as a compression algorithm (modified Limpel/Ziv 77 with Huffman Trees). But thanks for catching me up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with the following code.  It does not make any assumptions about which string is longer.

```
string A = "1234";
string B = "567890";

char[] chars = new char[A.Length + B.Length];
int charsIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < A.Length || i < B.Length; i++)
{
    if(i < A.Length)
        chars[charsIndex++] = A[i];
    if(i < B.Length)
        chars[charsIndex++] = B[i];
}
string result = new string(chars);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: This is working as expected.